# How to use ggplot to plot a list of dataframes and save them in a pdf file

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I have a data frame with this structure

| date | Campaign_name | reach | impressions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06/06/2021 | generic | 1423412 | 32423 |
| 06/06/2021 | remarketing | 232 | 234 |
| 06/06/2021 | generic | 213213 | 23423 |
| 06/06/2021 | remarketing | 123213 | 23423 |
| 06/06/2021 | generic | 214332 | 23423 |
| 06/06/2021 | remarketing | 32423 | 23423 |
| 06/06/2021 | generic | 234 | 213213 |
| 07/06/2021 | remarketing | 234234 | 213123 |
| 07/06/2021 | generic | 234234 | 5465 |
| 07/06/2021 | remarketing | 234234 | 21321 |
| 07/06/2021 | remarketing | 234234 | 786786 |
| 07/06/2021 | remarketing | 2342342 | 785785 |
| 07/06/2021 | acquisition | 543454345 | 786774 |
| 07/06/2021 | acquisition | 435345 | 758785 |
| 07/06/2021 | generic | 2344234 | 7557 |
| 08/06/2021 | remarketing | 213123 | 7857 |
| 08/06/2021 | remarketing | 234234 | 7857 |
| 08/06/2021 | generic | 234324 | 757 |
| 08/06/2021 | remarketing | 545345345345 | 7857 |
| 08/06/2021 | generic | 3423 | 78578 |
| 08/06/2021 | acquisition | 32423 | 7578 |
| 08/06/2021 | acquisition | 2343 | 7587 |
| 09/06/2021 | acquisition | 23423 | 7578578 |
| 09/06/2021 | acquisition | 2212 | 785787878 |
| 09/06/2021 | acquisition | 23234 | 785757 |
| 09/06/2021 | remarketing | 2342 | 7575757 |
| 09/06/2021 | remarketing | 23423 | 578575857 |
| 09/06/2021 | generic | 23423 | 785757 |
| 09/06/2021 | acquisition | 23432 | 78575 |
| 09/06/2021 | generic | 234 | 7857757 |

I need to make multiple plots for every campaign_name, for example:

a plot a time series for the *generic* campaign name with *reach* and *impression* on the y axis

and save it to a pdf

I need to repeat this task for every type of campaign inside the campaign name column

I have tried this

```
list_of_campaigns <- unique(facebook_raw_daily$`Campaign name`)

facebook_split <- split(facebook_raw_daily, facebook_raw_daily$`Campaign name`)



p <- lapply(facebook_split, function(d)  ggplot(
  data = d,
  aes(
    x = "date",
    y = "reach",
    group = "Campaign_name",
    colour = "Campaign_name"
  )
) + geom_line() )

pdf("myplots2.pdf")
do.call("grid.arrange", p)
dev.off()
```

it generates a pdf file with multiple plots but they are blank and all inside one page which is not feasible, I would like to have a plot per page

Any suggestion?

Comment: The purpose of grid.arrange is to put all the plots generated in the list as a single image. If you want to plot one plot per page, try `print(p)` instead of grid.arrange within your pdf printout function.

Comment: @AdamQuek do.call(print(p),p) works but the plots are empty, I can't get why

Comment: Instead of `aes` use `aes_string`. https://rdrr.io/cran/ggplot2/man/aes_.html